# Progress through multiple Zurb Foundation modals using Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller, zurb-foundation

I'm using Rails 4 and the Zurb Foundation framework and am trying to make a simple quiz.  You launch the quiz from a Lesson page.  Foundation provides a way to move from one modal to another (each modal links to the next), which I understand well enough, but mine is a bit more complicated because I have a form on each modal and need to route the user's input through my LessonsController 'check' action before loading the next modal.  So I'm not redirecting to another page.  I just need to activate the link that brings up the next modal if the answer is correct.

Here is the first modal that is launched from the Lesson page:

```
<div id="lesson1Modal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
  <div class="row">
    <%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'lessons', :action => 'check'), method: :get do %>
      <div class="small-4 columns">
        <%= @lesson.problems.first.content %>
      </div>
      <div class="small-8 columns">
        <%= text_field_tag :guess %>
      </div>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :lesson_id, @lesson.id %>

    <%= submit_tag "Check your answer!", class: 'button tiny' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my `LessonsController`:

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  end

  def check
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:lesson_id])
    @user = current_user
    if params[:guess] == @lesson.problems.first.answer
      # here I need an equivalent for what Zurb's button for launching a second modal from the      
      # first: # <a href="#" data-reveal-id="one-2" class="secondary button">Continue</a>
    else
      # retry the problem
    end
  end
end
```

So I need the controller to bring up the modal with data-reveal-id="one-2".  Can anyone help with this?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create a file: `check.js.erb`

```
if (<%= @variable_set_in_controller %>){
      $(".close-reveal-modal").click();
      $("#LinkTo2ndModal").click(); //Or use foundation's js to call it programmatically
}else{
  alert("Wrong!");
}
```

This should trigger automatically by the controller since there is no `check.html.erb` to redirect to.